# django-rest-auth password change responds with ErrorDetails object

Tags: django, django-rest-auth

I am using `django-rest-auth` for authentication using APIs. I am writing tests for checking whether my application works accordingly when password1 and password2 are not same. 
I am recieveing an ErrorDetail object instead of string in resposnse.

Response :

`{'new_password2': [ErrorDetail(string='The two password fields didn’t match.', code='invalid')]}`

Expected response :

`{'new_password2': 'The two password fields didn’t match.'}`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the error object to string using `str()`.